# Securing the file system of an IoT device

Tags: linux, security, sd-card

I am working on an IoT device network for my job and I need to secure the devices on the network. I have done some basic steps like preventing any login on the root user and using key pairs to connect through SSH. Now I'm faced with a problem I can't seem to fix which is the removable SD card. The device runs on DietPi with a Raspberry PI. There is some proprietary code in Python that queries an API. I'm wondering how I can 1) secure the code, 2) ensure it hasn't been altered. Assuming the user have access to the code by simply removing the SD card and plugging it in his/her machine, storing an encryption key on the system seems quite useless. Any solutions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried superglue? Physical access will always beat your security. Best to just make sure it's not accessible remotely, then encase it in glue.

Comment: Thanks for the giggle. Is it a joke or is it really not something i can protect against ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super-glue is not a joke.

You need to physically secure your device.

If super-gluing the sd-card in place to discourage removing isn't something you want to do, a lock-box with cable ports would be your next option.

Comment: Instead of preventing access would it be more possible to then detect fraudulent access ? Maybe a checksum of the entire Python code to detect any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

So after further analysis we concluded 2 things.

1) Access to the physical SD card would only be useful for people that wants to do harm to the devices its connected with, which can be done by simply hitting it with a hammer (lmao).
2) It would be useful to circumvent the paywall of the SaaS for the over arching network which can be prevented by deleting the code when locking someone out and/or physically taking the device from the client.

Since the access to both data and logic is locked within an authentication barrier, I was mistaken in thinking this is our responsibility and/or a necessary security measure.